# Uncaught ReferenceError: $scope is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Receiving the error when the page is loaded. I'm trying to append a new object to an array of entries.

[image]

[image]

What is wrong with the code?

**index.html**

## Raffler

```
<div ng-controller="RaffleCtrl">

  <form ng-sumbit="addEntry">
    <input type="text" ng-model="newEntry.name">
    <input type="submit" value="Add">
  </form>

  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="entry in entries">{{entry.name}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**raffle.js**

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller("RaffleCtrl", function ($scope) {
  $scope.entries = [
      {
        name: "Larry"
      }, {
        name: "Curly"
      }, {
        name: "Moe"
      }
    ]
});

$scope.addEntry = function () {
  $scope.entries($scope.newEntry)
  $scope.newEntry = {}
};
```

Comment: Did you add the references for the jscript before your own scripts?
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/js/myscripts"></script>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You wrongly used `$scope` outside the controller. Use the `$scope` inside the controller

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller("RaffleCtrl", function ($scope) {
  $scope.entries = [
      {
        name: "Larry"
      }, {
        name: "Curly"
      }, {
        name: "Moe"
      }
    ];

   $scope.addEntry = function () {
     $scope.entries($scope.newEntry)
     $scope.newEntry = {}
   };
});
```

Comment: @BillyLogan - Glad it helps :-)

Answer (score 2):

if you really want to keep it outside

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller("RaffleCtrl", function ($scope) {
  $scope.entries = [
      {
        name: "Larry"
      }, {
        name: "Curly"
      }, {
        name: "Moe"
      }
    ];
  $scope.addEntry = addEntry;
});

function addEntry() {
  $scope.entries($scope.newEntry)
  $scope.newEntry = {}
};
```